# Possible to modify widget tree without keeping my own representation of the tree structure?

Tags: flutter, tree, widget

I would like to be able to insert (or change) specific widgets at positions based on a key (or some other id), like e.g. the `insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode)` function in javascript.

---

Of course, I can rebuild the widget tree each time some widget is inserted or changed repeating all the steps used for a previous build.

However, in my case the tree will be created based on some user input (more specifically: based on lua code with [LuaDardo](https://github.com/arcticfox1919/flutter_lua_dardo)), and I would like to avoid parsing the full user input each time again and also avoid to keep my own copy of the tree structure - as it is available somewhere in flutter anyway, isn't it?

I just want to create the tree for example like this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey _key1 = GlobalKey(), _key2 = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              key: _key1,
              child: const Text(
                'Text1',
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              key: _key2,
              child: const Text(
                'Text2',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And then, when some Button is pressed, i would like to call something like

```
_key1a=GlobalKey();
insertBefore(key: _key2, widget: Container(
              key: _key1a,
              child: const Text(
                'Text1a',
              ),
            ));
```

... resulting in a Column containing "Text1", "Text1a", "Text2".

Any suggestions how to code the insertBefore function?

I am thinking about `context.visitChildElements(visitor)` but I am not sure how to use it or how to insert a widget once I found the correct position.

Also `find.byKey(key)` might be an option, but this seems to be available only for testing?

Answer (score 0):

this is what you can think of to do:
you make a map of widgets and the map keys will be your widget keys

example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title = "Flutter Demo Home Page";

  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Map<String, Widget> w = {
    'a': const Text(
      'a',
    ),
    'b': const Text(
      'b',
    ),
    'd': const Text(
      'd',
    ),
  };

  insertBefore(String keyBefore, String newKey, Widget newWidget) {
    int index = w.keys.toList().indexOf(keyBefore);
    Map<String, Widget> newMap = {};
    newMap.addEntries(w.entries.toList().sublist(0, index));
    newMap.addEntries({newKey: newWidget}.entries);
    newMap.addEntries(w.entries.toList().sublist(index));
    setState(() {
      w = newMap;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          insertBefore('d', 'c', const Text('c'));
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ...w.values,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that would do the job, if I have only one level of widgets and not a treelike structure. If I need nested widgets, I probably have to use a Map<String, dynamic> so that in addition to the widgets I can also store a sub-map of children with their keys...
And then in insertBefore I would have to search recursively through the tree, and also the `children: <Widget>[ ...w.values,],` part becomes more complicated.

I was hoping to avoid all this, because all the information should be available in flutter, but maybe it is not accessible there?

Comment: oh I understand, wow I see that complicated in flutter, but it's interesting.